# JSON in NSData objects for common rest API

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, nsdata

I'm trying to send data from my app to a rest API that is also being used by an Android app developed by another programmer. I have the JSON being converted into an NSData object using NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject and then attaching it to a NSURLRequest but the NSData object is a hexadecimal representation of the JSON String. According to the other developer his Android code is creating and transmitting the JSON object in UTF-8 encoding, so my question is how do I either send the JSON string as UTF-8 text or what is the best way to make the API able to handle both sources as seamlessly as possible?

EDIT: The code that I'm using now

```
func postToServer() {

    let endPoint: String = "http://server.com"
    guard let url = NSURL(string: endPoint) else {
        print("ERROR: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    urlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let loc = self.getLocation()
    var content:[String: AnyObject] = ["action": "put-point", "request": ["rangeKey": self.id, "lng": loc.coordinate.longitude, "lat": loc.coordinate.latitude, "count": self.count]]

    var data: NSData! = NSData()
    do {
        data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(content, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
        print(data)
    } catch {
        print ("Error")
    }

    urlRequest.HTTPBody = data

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)


    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler:{ data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("ERROR: Cannot call Get on endpoint")
            print(error)
            return
        }

        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("ERROR: Did not receive any data")
            return
        }

        print("DATA: \(data)")

    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
let jsonObj = [...]
var data = NSData()

do {
    data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonObj, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
} catch {
    print("error:  \(error)")
}
```

*Tried on Swift 2 & Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: I did try that but I can't attach the NSString to the urlRequest.HTTPBody because it wants a NSData object. I'll update the question with the code I'm using right now.